# Evaluation of variance components - mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nonlinear

How can I evaluate if the variance components of a nonlinear mixed model make sense (assuming or not assuming treatments factor)? For instance, if I am assuming an unstructured variance-covariance specification for the random effects, how can I be sure that this is correct for my study case. 
Note: I am contrasting the nonlinear response (parameters) of different treatments (fixed effects) against a control treatment.

Comment: What is the relation between assuming treatment effect and variance components?

Comment: I am not really sure. I would say that none since the treatment effects is represented by the fixed effects, while the random effects are modeling the variability of my subjects (or grouping structure).

Comment: Then keep the fixed effect no change, fit two models with and without random effect. Compare their (log) likelihood values.

Comment: Typically people use variance components to refer to a model with no predictors and a random intercept. If that is what you are doing, then user158565's approach is spot on. But you mention an unstructured variance-covariance matrix, which implies that you also have random slopes in the model. Is that what you have? And if so, do you also have the fixed effect predictor(s) for the random slope(s) in your model?

Comment: @user158565 Thanks! I have implemented the approach and it does make sense. In my study case, any variance-covariance structure (for instance unstructured) improved the fit (the AIC and BIC were lower, while the (log) likelihood comparison was significant).

Comment: @ErikRuzek Thanks for the comment. I would say that is random intercept and random slopes. I am working with a nonlinear model, thus there is a fixed effect based on the treatments (parameters of the nonlinear fit in function of the treatment, which no control treatment parameters are compared to the control one), and random effect which model parameters are normally distribuited around. Therefore, I have a prediction (fixed effect) for each treatment, and a prediction (random effect) for each subject. Is it clear?

Comment: It is clear, more or less. You only have a random intercept. Your slopes for the treatment are fixed (non-varying across clusters). The likelihood comparison test, as well as the lower AIC  and BIC favoring the random intercept model are all telling you that you have non-negligible variation across clusters in your outcome. To ignore it and run a model without somehow accounting for it would be wrong. Thus, you can move forward with modeling your outcome using a mixed effects/multilevel model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the clarification about the random intercept.